# Сравнение элементов матрицы по столбцам С++

Tags: c++

Вечер добрый. Задание такого характера.

Ввести целочисленную квадратную матрицу размером. Найти номера столбцов, все элементы которых одинаковы. Обязательно условие должно задаваться через while.

Суть моей проблемы такова: в конце кода есть как раз то самое сравнение элементов 2 столбца. Он его не видит, как собственно и 3,4 столбец и так далее. Видит и проверяет только 1. В чем моя ошибка? Спасибо заранее!

Код такой:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include<iomanip>; 

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int i, j;
    int mass[4][4];

    i = 0;
    while (i<4)
    {
        j = 0;
        while (j<4)
        {
            cin >> mass[i][j];
            j = j + 1;
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (i<4)
    {
        j = 0;
        while (j<4)
        {
            cout << setw(10) << mass[i][j];
            j = j + 1;
        }
        cout << endl;
        i = i + 1;
    }

    while (mass[0][1] == mass[1][1] == mass[2][1] == mass[3][1])
    {
        cout << " nomer stolbca=2\n"; break;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Это уже третье изменение в коде. Ставлю на то, что это не тот код, который вы исполняете.

Comment: Все , я написал тот самый код, который у меня не работает. Я хочу проверить второй столбец, но он не проверяет и не выдает нужную и правильную информацию. Вы можете мне с этим помочь?

Comment: `mass[0][1] == mass[1][1] == mass[2][1] == mass[3][1]` - как Вы думаете, что это делает?

Comment: Берете отладчик и смотрите, что, с чем вы сравниваете, как оно все работает. Нет смысла писать вам код, если вы не желаете разбираться.

Comment: вот это `mass[0][1] == mass[1][1]` сравнивает два числа и возвращает `true` или `false`. A вот это `mass[0][1] == mass[1][1] == mass[2][1]` сравнивает то `true` или `false` с третьим числом. Результат понятен?

Comment: `(mass[0][1] == mass[1][1] && mass[0][1] == mass[2][1] && mass[0][1] == mass[3][1])`

Comment: Вы бы, умники,  вместо того, что бы давать абстрактные советы типа учи матчасть и тд, лучше бы помогли, ровно так же, как помогали вам в свое время. Каждый человек, который достиг какого либо уровня в совершенно любом деле, должен снисходительно относиться к новичкам и помогать им. Давай удочку, а не рыбу, это грамотно. Но сегодня я сидел над этим пол дня , изучал все свойства while,массива и как это должно работать между собой.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68107/discussion-on-question-by-------).

Answer (score 1):

Могу сказать что никто ничего не видит это точно. Дело в том, что ваш код который должен, по-вашему, сравнивать элементы массива, делает совсем не то, что вы ожидаете:

```
while (mass[0][1] == mass[1][1] == mass[2][1] == mass[3][1])
{
    cout << " nomer stolbca=2\n"; break;
}
```

Во-первых оператор `while` тут плохо подходит, логичнее здесь использовать оператор `if`.

Главная же беда в выражении `mass[0][1] == mass[1][1] == mass[2][1] == mass[3][1]`. Это выражение компилятор трактует вот так: `(((mass[0][1] == mass[1][1]) == mass[2][1]) == mass[3][1])`. То есть сначала выполняется сравнение `mass[0][1] == mass[1][1]` результатом которого будет булево значение `true` или `false`. Исходное выражение сокращается до `(((bool) == mass[2][1]) == mass[3][1])`. Потом полученный `bool` нужно сравнить с `mass[2][1]`, но `mass[2][1]` имеет тип `int`, поэтому `bool` неявно приводится к `int` и уже это значение (0 или 1) сравнивается с `mass[2][1]`. Далее все повторятся, выражение сокращается до `((bool) == mass[3][1])`. Ну и так далее.

К сожалению для вас и современного Си++ то, что вы написали это синтаксически правильное выражение, но делает оно совсем не то что ожидается.

Правильно было бы делать так:

```
if(mass[0][1] == mass[1][1] && mass[0][1] == mass[2][1] && mass[0][1] == mass[3][1])
{
    cout << " nomer stolbca=2\n";
}
```

Это выражение трактуется так: `((mass[0][1] == mass[1][1]) && (mass[0][1] == mass[2][1])) && (mass[0][1] == mass[3][1])`